# Getting "ValueError: Entries in boundaries must be strictly increasing." , during training using tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I was trying to train my own dataset using tensorflow object detection API. So for this, at first I labeled my dataset using [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg). From that I got a xml file with the labeling information. Then I convert those data to tfrecord using a script. As I was trying to do transfer learning using faster rasnet inception v2 model, I changes the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config based on my information. Finally I run the model_main.py to train my data. But getting the following value error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main.py", line 105, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 367, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/anaconda3/envs/kashem/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1146, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/Desktop/Astro/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 374, in model_fn
    train_config.optimizer)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/Desktop/Astro/models/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py", line 56, in build
    global_step=global_step)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/Desktop/Astro/models/research/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py", line 124, in _create_learning_rate
    learning_rate_sequence, config.warmup)
  File "/home/mahbubcseju/Desktop/Astro/models/research/object_detection/utils/learning_schedules.py", line 187, in manual_stepping
    raise ValueError('Entries in boundaries must be strictly increasing.')
ValueError: Entries in boundaries must be strictly increasing
```

.

How to get rid of this error. Badly need some suggestion on this.

Comment: can you share your modified pipeline config. I suspect that pipeline config is not modified correctly.